# AWS: how to log into management console in browser via *username*/password, NOT via *email*/password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, login

For years, I have had a personal AWS account (for developer purposes) in which I've created various EC2 instances at different times.

Today, one of my clients has asked me to log into his AWS account in order to create an instance.  He provided his **username** (not an email address) and **password**.

I assumed that logging in to my client's account would be perfectly straightforward.

First, I went to http://aws.amazon.com and clicked "My Account / Console" -> "AWS Management Console", as shown in this screenshot:

[image: aws.amazon.com]

Upon clicking "AWS Management Console", the following login page appears:

[image: login at aws]

**Notice that this login page requires an email address.**  Unfortunately, my client did not provide me with an email address, but rather with a username (not an email address).  I attempted to use this username (and the password provided to me), but the error `There was a problem with your request` appears, as shown in this image:

[image: failed AWS login]

I have also had a previous client who utilized AIM, so I attempted to use the `AIM users sign-in link` (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_AccessingConsole.html) of the form `https://My_AWS_Account_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/`.  I attempted to use this URL (with my client's username in place of `My_AWS_Account_ID`), but the URL was dead.

I then emailed my client explaining the issue.

Here is my client's response:

> Go to
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/
>
> Select "My Account / Console" | "AWS Management Console"
>
> You should get this:
>
> (see image below)
>
> That's all I usually need to do. Let me know if there is a problem.

Here is the image referenced in the above quote:

[image: different AWS login with username and password]

Lo and behold, the screenshot included by my client prompts for a *username* and password (not *email* and password)!  (Note that my client also provided the `Account` required for the login page.)  In an attempt to access this login page, I manually typed the URL I see in the screenshot: `https://signin.aws.amazon.com` - but I was re-routed back to the login page prompting for the **email** and password.

What is going on here?  Why is it impossible for me to access the login page that my client indicates?  Why does my client indicate the identical set of steps to access the login page, but this results in a *different* login page when I try it?

Most importantly, how do I access the same login page that my client sees - the one prompting for a *username* and password (as well as account name), rather than an *email* and password?

Comment: What did Amazon tell you when you contacted them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `https://My_AWS_Account_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console`, the value you are looking for to replace `My_AWS_Account_ID` is not the username... it's the *account* name (the account under which the username exists).

It's also, presumably, the value you blacked-out under "Account" in the screenshot you posted.

Put those two pieces of information together and at the newly-crafted url, you should find the login screen you're looking for.

Comment: Sometimes the obvious is staring you in the face.  Thanks!

Comment: Amazon AWS doesn't make it easy!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the AWS Alias Configured then you would use

**https://Your_AWS_Account_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/**

if an alias is configure then

**https://Your_Alias.signin.aws.amazon.com/console/**

Apparently the URL for the AWS IAM Login is quite hard to remember. I have created this site to navigate to the respective IAM Console's Login page by just remembering the alias or the account number.

> [**www.awsiamlogin.com**](http://www.awsiamlogin.com)

[image]